# EF many to many relationship is not adding records for one of the entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

So I'm following the book `Entity Framework 6 Recipes`. I am using `Visual Studio 2017`, `.NET 4.6.1` and `EF 6.2.0`.

I've created this simple DB structure:

```
CREATE TABLE Album
(
    AlbumId INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    AlbumName NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Album] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([AlbumId] ASC)
)

CREATE TABLE Artist
(
    ArtistId INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    FirstName NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    MiddleName NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    LastName NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Artist] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (ArtistId ASC)
)

CREATE TABLE LinkTable
(
    ArtistId INT NOT NULL,
    AlbumId INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT FK_LinkTable_Artist FOREIGN KEY (ArtistId) REFERENCES dbo.Artist (ArtistId),
    CONSTRAINT FK_LinkTable_Album FOREIGN KEY (AlbumId) REFERENCES dbo.Album (AlbumId)
)
ALTER TABLE LinkTable ADD CONSTRAINT PK_LinkTable PRIMARY KEY (ArtistId, AlbumId)
```

and in the code I have this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    SeedMusicData();    
    ListMusicData();
}
```

The problem is when I try to add new records to the database. If in the `SeedMusicData()` I have this:

```
private static void SeedMusicData()
{
    using (var context = new MusicEntities())
    {
        var artist = new Artist { FirstName = "Alan", LastName = "Jackson", MiddleName = "X." };
        var album1 = new Album { AlbumName = "Drive" };
        var album2 = new Album { AlbumName = "Live at Texas stadium" };

        artist.Albums.Add(album1);
        artist.Albums.Add(album2);

        context.Artists.Add(artist);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

then everything works fine and the data is stored in the database.

However if I try to do it like this:

```
private static void SeedMusicData()
{
    using (var context = new MusicEntities())
    {
        var artist1 = new Artist { FirstName ="Tobby", LastName = "Keith", MiddleName = "Y." };
        var artist2 = new Artist { FirstName = "Merle", LastName = "Haggard", MiddleName = "Z." };
        var album = new Album { AlbumName = "Hokytonk University"};
        artist1.Albums.Add(album);
        artist2.Albums.Add(album);

        context.Albums.Add(album); //use Albums instead Artists when it works

        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Then nothing is stored in the database, I don't get some sort of exception either. And I think I'm following the book literally except for this one:

```
ALTER TABLE LinkTable ADD CONSTRAINT PK_LinkTable PRIMARY KEY (ArtistId, AlbumId)
```

Since I was getting error which seemed to be caused by the lack of primary key for the junction table, and after adding one the error was fixed. But I wonder if this could be the cause of the problem.

**P.S**

So some additional info:

This is how the model looks in VS designer:

[image: Music.edmx]

And inside `Music.tt` I have:

Album.cs:

```
public partial class Album
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public Album()
        {
            this.Artists = new HashSet<Artist>();
        }

        public int AlbumId { get; set; }
        public string AlbumName { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Artist> Artists { get; set; }
    }
```

And Artist.cs:

```
public partial class Artist
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public Artist()
        {
            this.Albums = new HashSet<Album>();
        }

        public int ArtistId { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string MiddletName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Album> Albums { get; set; }
    }
```

The junction table is in the DataBase but from what I understand it's expected for EF to not include it if it only contains the two Foreign Keys.

Comment: Sorry.. I don't understand. Does your LinkTable have a primary key?

Comment: @FabrizioAccatino Is it unclear? The `SQL` script for the database is at the beginning and at the end I mentioned the `LinkTable` again since I am not 100% sure if the composite PK is not causing a change in the expected behavior.

Comment: For EF related questions, database tables are usually irrelevant (except they are out of sync with the entity model). We need to see the entity model. Also are you saying that in the second case even album is not added to the database?

Comment: @IvanStoev Can you look at the `P.S` and see if it helps? I saw your edit. Yes, I'm sure I keep my Management studio open and check. Nothing is inserted  for the second case.

Comment: @IvanStoev I don't know how to strike text so I'll add another comment. Actually you are right. The album is in the DataBase. The artists are missing however. Just checked!

Comment: All good then. When working with the other side as in your second case, add the related entity to the collection of the entity, e.g. `album.Artists.Add(artist1); album.Artists.Add(artist2);`

Comment: @IvanStoev I'm not sure what are you suggesting. In the example which doesn't work I have `artist1.Albums.Add(album)` and `artist2.Albums.Add(album)`. So two different artists for the same album.

Comment: Since in the non working example you are only adding album to the db context, you should all artists to the album, not album to artists :) If you want to be safe, in both scenarios add all artists and all albums to the db context first, then add links in one or the other way.

Comment: @IvanStoev OK. What bugs me is that this is the exact code from the book, so.. Yeah, I really wonder why it is like that there. However. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SeedMusicData, add artists to album instead of adding album to artist.

```
album.Artist.Add(artist1);
album.Artist.Add(artist2);
context.Album.Add(album);    
context.SaveChanges();
```

When you add album, it will also "bring" artists during SaveChanges.

UPDATE: if you want, you can check the State of your entities before SaveChanges:

```
var s1 = context.Entry(artist1).State;
var s2 = context.Entry(artist2).State;
var sx = context.Entry(album).State;
```

If you add artists to the album, all the entries will be marked as "Added". If you add the album to artists, album entry will be marked as "Added" but artists entries will be marked as "Detached". Detached entries will be not processed by SaveChanges resulting in an incomplete database update.

Comment: There is a lot of different approaches to make this work. What I want to know is why this specific approach is not working (for me) and how to make it work.

Comment: I added more details. Hope they help.

Comment: Thanks. I can see this is working. However this is pretty simple task, and seems to me that I'm following the book literally so what bugs me is why this exact case is not working. Is this just a mistake in the book. Is there some change from `EF 6.0` to `EF 6.2` in order for this not to be working... Or am I doing something wrong?